# Execute command at beginning/end of every paragraph

Tags: vim

Can anyone suggest a way to execute a command at the beginning of every paragraph (especially within the visual selection)? For instance, I wrote a document in plain text and now I want to convert it to HTML so one thing I'll do is wrap every paragraph in `<p>` and `</p>`.

**Edit:**

The only thing I've come up with so far is something like `:'<,'>g/^\s*$/normal o<p>^[` to insert the `<p>` tag at the beginning of the paragraph, and the same but with a *capital* `O` to add the end tag at the end of the paragraph. Obviously this hits any blank line though, so if there are multiple lines between paragraphs, it will insert additional unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command :

```
g/\v(\_^\s*\n)@<=\S/normal O<p>^[}o</p>
```

**`^[` is `C-V <ESC>`**

The `\v` turns on "verymagic" so that the rest of the pattern is easier to write. The parenthesis wrap a subexpression which matches the start of the line (`\_^`), any amount of whitepsace (`\s*`) and then the end of line (`\n`) (so in other words, a blank line). The `@<=` means that the preceding subexpression is not actually included in the matched text, but is required to match. Then any non-whitespace character (`\S`) concludes the matching pattern.

it works here like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just install [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) and enjoy life again:

Select your paragraph then do `s<p>`.

Comment: in fact, without surround it could be done by `q` as well. however, the problem is, OP wants visual select a bunch of text, and those paragraphs within the selection should be "surrounded" by tags.

Comment: That's not efficient when there are lots of paragraphs.